# quick way to adduser and userdel in multiple machines

Tags: linux, user-accounts, multiple-computers

Currently I just go to each of our servers to type

> `adduser <username> --firstuid 1101 --gid 1001 --disabled-password`

to add a user. Is there a quicker way to do so on all servers at the same time? Thanks.

UPDATE:

After running the above command, some user information is required to be filled: "Full Name:","Room Number", "Work Phone", etc. I would like to only fill in this information once and to be used for the user creation on all machines. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UPDATE

I am not sure if you need to add the *same* users to each server or if each server has its own user. I will give you a solution for either situation.

### Adding a list of users to each server

The best tool for this job is `newusers`. You will need to create a text file containing the list of users and their details. If you want to add the *same* user to each server, this file will only need one line.

1. Create the user's list. The general format of the file is

   ```
   username:passwd:UID:GID:full name,room number,work phone,home phone,other:directory:shell
   ```

   So, in your case, you would need to use something like

   ```
   tom:password1:::"Tom Hanks","101","123456","654321","Tall"::
   danny:password2:::"Danny DeVito","102","222333","333222","Short"::
   ```

   Note that I have left the UID, GUID, directory and shell options empty. This means that default values will be used.
2. Now that you have created the list, you will need to copy it to each remote machine and then add the new users. For this, you will still need a list of relevant hostnames or IPs, one per line, as in my previous suggestion. Once you have all this set up, save this little script as `newusers.sh`:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
      while read ip; do
        scp users.txt root@$ip:/home/root
        ssh root@$ip newusers users.txt
      done
   ```
3. Make the script executable (`chmod a+x newusers.sh`) and run it for each IP in your file:

   ```
   newusers.sh < IPs.txt
   ```
4. This will all be much easier if you have password-less ssh set up. If you don't, run the following commands to use ssh keys allowing password-less access (you will still need a passphrase):

   ```
   ssh-keygen -t rsa
   while read ip; do ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub root@$ip; done < IPs.txt
   ```

### Adding a different user to each server

In this case, I would create a slightly different file. It should have an IP or hostname, its corresponding user and the details needed to create her on each line. Assuming you want to set up passwords, you can have the plain text (obviously some security concerns here, don't know if they are relevant in your case) password as the fourth field. Also, in order to correctly parse names with spaces, **make sure you use a non-space charcater as field separator**. In the example below, I am using `-` :

```
192.168.1.10-tom-"Tom Hanks","101","123456","654321","Tall"-pass1
192.168.1.10-danny-"Danny DeVito","102","222333","333222","Short"-pass2
```

Now loop through the file and create each user on the corresponding machine. Make sure to set the `IFS` variabe to your field separator in order to parse spaces correctly:

```
while IFS='-' read ip name opts pass; do \
   ssh root@$ip useradd $name -mc $opts -p `openssl passwd $pass` -s /bin/bash \
done < list.txt
```

Comment: hmhm.... in this case, I will still need to input all the duplicated details (name, office, tel num, etc.). Any other ideas? Thanks.

Comment: @Kenneth a centralized user database is probably a good idea. However, if you were to update your question to include your _full_ requirements, I should be able to modify my answer. What are the duplicated details? What is the _actual_ command you need to type on each server? You could just add them to the file with the IPS and usernames.

Comment: thanks terdon. I checked the man page of adduser, it doesn't seem there is any option to put the user detail, eg. Full name, Room num, etc. in the command line. Note that the Full name most likely contains space. Thanks.

Comment: Fantastic terdon!!! Thanks heaps. sorry sor my slow response as I was stuck in other projects and just got back to managing the servers.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use some centralized user database, like LDAP (either OpenLDAP or better [389  Directory Server](http://directory.fedoraproject.org))?

Comment: I got no idea what LDAP is. Just had a look at the wiki, it's for organising a set of records. How to use it for user management in Operating System? Thanks.

Comment: LDAP is used exactly to keep records on _users_. Perhaps looking a http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-openldap helps.