# How to migrate the password of a user to another server?

Tags: linux, debian, passwords, user-management

I'm migrating users from an old server to a new one. It's only a few users, we want to migrate only the active ones and reorganize groups in the process, so I'm doing it manually. One problem remains: How can I migrate their passwords to the new server? Is there a better way than copying password hashes from `/etc/shadow` by hand?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found [`chpasswd`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/chpasswd) tool. With `-e` it accepts a list of users with their encrypted passwords to set. It's just what I've been looking for.

Answer (score 4):

Since there are few enough accounts for you to migrate manually I think lifting the hashes by hand is the way to go. That's how I'd do it atleast.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how lifting hashes by hand. I assume this means copying hashed passwords, i.e. items between second and third colons in lines for eligible users, from /etc/shadow on source system and pasting them into corresponding lines on target system. Right?

Comment: @Drux Right. Just copy the appropriate lines from /etc/shadow. Or if the user has a line in the target file, just copy the password hash. It's the only field that looks like gibberish. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Well, you wouldn't need to do it *by hand*. Just use `lastlog` to get the list of users who have logged on at least once in, for example, the past year and then `grep` them in `/etc/shadow`:

```
  lastlog -t 365 | gawk '{print $1}' | tail -n +2 | while read n; do \
   grep -w $n /etc/shadow; done
```

You could also automate the user creation on the new server as described in my answer [here](https://superuser.com/a/543376/151431).

Comment: TBH I'm not sure, and my first experiments aren't very successful. But I don't know any other way how to do it.

Comment: Copying shadow lines does work; I did it not too long ago during a server move with lots of users. It broke a few users, but almost all still worked.